# How to write Linq query for fetching records

Tags: c#, linq

Hi I am quite new to LINQ.

I want to fetch records from datatable that returns `(System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection'1[System.Data.DataRow])` in `result` while debuging

Below is my code. Please help.

```
DataTable dt = HttpContext.Current.Application["AlarmTypeListCache"] as
DataTable; //data table from cache
var results = (from myRow in dt.AsEnumerable()
        where myRow["PARAM_TYPE_ID"] == paramtypeID //203
        && myRow["FLAG"] == flag select myRow)
    .ToList();//flag A
//no records in result while data exist in datatable
```

data exists in data table for given parameter

Comment: And you have a row returned. Did you expand the item in the debugger?

Comment: And what do you want to do with the result? What is your actual question?

Comment: i want fetch all records in results those flag and param id will match

Answer (score 3):

Plase try this,

```
var results = from data in dt 
    where data.PARAM_TYPE_ID== paramtypeID && data.FLAG == flag  
    select data;
```

this answer taken from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397927.aspx

Comment: compile time error in dt on above code

Comment: please visit above microsoft link for more reference

Comment: Cast the datatable as the the table type you are querying assuming the corresponding table is a database table object